# Write JavaScript code in MVC Razor foreach loop

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I would like to embed javascript code in razor code. I've tried the following-

```
   <tbody>
        @foreach (var row in ViewBag.Retailers.Rows) //Retailers is a datatable
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@row["RegionName"].ToString()</td>
            </tr>
            <script>
                  var marker=new Object();
                  marker.lat=@row["Latitude"].ToString();
                  marker.lon=@row["Longitude"].ToString();
                  markersArray.push(marker);
           </script>
        }

   </tbody>
```

But, it's not working. Any help?

Comment: What is `ViewBag.Retailers.Rows`?

Comment: A "DataTable" sent from controller.

Comment: I know this might be silly, but have you tried to remove the ; from the lat and long props?

Comment: Add the values as `data-*` attributes to the table row in the loop, then use one script at the end to build the array and avoid duplicating this script and rendering unnecessary html.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Would you please post an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To mix razor with JavaScript, you need to include razor code in single quotes `'` like this:

```
        <script>
              var marker=new Object();
              marker.lat='@row["Latitude"].ToString()';
              marker.lon='@row["Longitude"].ToString()';
              markersArray.push(marker);
       </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you avoid generating all these inline scripts and instead add the values as data attributes of the row

```
<tbody id="retailers">
  @foreach (var row in ViewBag.Retailers.Rows) //Retailers is a datatable
  {
    <tr data-latitude="@row["Latitude"]" data-longitude="@row["Longitude"]">
      <td>@row["RegionName"].ToString()</td>
    </tr>
  }
</tbody>
```

then have a single script to build your array

```
var markersArray = [];
$('#retailers tr').each(function() {
  markersArray.push({ lat: $(this).data('latitude'), lon: $(this).data('longitude') });
});
```